# How to install Ubuntu to use only part of a disk

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I have a 1TB disk, /dev/sda. I installed Ubuntu using default options and it took up the whole disk.

I would like to install Ubuntu in a 200GB partition and leave the rest for data so that I can refresh my Ubuntu as and when I like it without destroying my data.

I see that under `Installation Type` there is `Something else` where I can specify the partition size. However, when I tried it it keeps saying something like no file system at /.  How do I use this option to install Ubuntu on 200GB, assuming that this is a fresh disk and nothing currently on it need to be preserved?

Comment: "2. Manually setting up the partition layout for Ubuntu" in the weblink above shows you how to manually allocate space.

Comment: Thanks, I have done according to the article above, creating three partitions: swap, /, and /home.  When it was shutting down after installation there were many errors, but upon rebooting it appeared ok,